# Compute $\sum^{2024}_{k=1} \frac{2023-2022 \cos \left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2024} \right)}{2021-2020 \cos \left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2024} \right)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation, contest-math

Question: Compute $$\sum^{2024}_{k=1} \frac{2023-2022 \cos \left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2024} \right)}{2021-2020 \cos \left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2024} \right)}$$

I began by rearranging the sum as follows:

$$\sum^{2024}_{k=1} \frac{2023-2022 \cos \left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2024} \right)}{2021-2020 \cos \left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2024} \right)}$$

$$=\sum^{2024}_{k=1} \left(1+\frac{2-2\cos \left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2024} \right)}{2021-2020 \cos \left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2024} \right)} \right)$$

$$=2024+\frac{1}{1010} \sum^{2024}_{k=1} \frac{2020-2020\cos \left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2024} \right)}{2021-2020 \cos \left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2024} \right)}$$

$$=2024+\frac{1}{1010} \sum^{2024}_{k=1} \left(1-\frac{1}{2021-2020 \cos \left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2024} \right)} \right)$$

$$=\frac{1011 \cdot 1012}{505}-\frac{1}{1010} \sum^{2024}_{k=1} \frac{1}{2021-2020 \cos \left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2024} \right)}$$

$$=\frac{1011 \cdot 1012}{505}-\frac{1}{2 \cdot 1010^2} \sum^{2024}_{k=1} \frac{1}{\frac{2021}{2020}-\cos \left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2024} \right)}$$

So, I then turned my attention to trying to find $\sum^{2024}_{k=1} \frac{1}{\frac{2021}{2020}-\cos \left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2024} \right)}$.

1. Complex numbers

I considered $z_k=e^{\frac{i \pi (2k-1)}{2024}}$ then observed $(z_k)^{2024}+1=0$. Then, I (mistakenly) believed that it was sufficient to find the real part of

$$\sum^{2024}_{k=1} \frac{1}{\frac{2021}{2020}-z_k}$$

For chuckles, I'll give a quick sketch of how I calculated this. Define $b_k$ to be the summand, and solve for $z_k$ in terms of $b_k$. Substitute this into the equation $(z_k)^{2024}+1=0$ and use Vieta's to find $\sum^{2024}_{k=1} b_k$.

2. Considering the derivative

Define $$f(x)=\prod^{2024}_{k=1} \left(x-\cos \left(\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2024} \right) \right)$$

Then, we know that

$$\sum^{2024}_{k=1} \frac{1}{x-\cos \left(\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2024} \right)}=\frac{f'\left(\frac{2021}{2020} \right)}{f \left(\frac{2021}{2020} \right)}$$

For the denominator, we can represent it in terms of Chebyshev polynomials as follows: $$f\left(\frac{2021}{2020} \right)=\frac{1}{2^{2022}} \left(T_{1012} \left(\frac{2021}{2020} \right) \right)^2$$

where $T_n$ is the $n$th Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind. It's annoying to calculate, but I think I could use the binomial theorem for this.

However, I have no idea how to compute $f'\left(\frac{2021}{2020} \right)$, so I'm at a dead end here as well.

Comment: FWIW, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+for+k%3D1+to+2024+of+%282023+-+2022+cos%28pi%282k-1%29%2F2024%29%29+%2F+%282021+-+2020+cos%28pi%282k-1%29%2F2024%29%29) gives the numerical answer of $2025.972436149946$, but fails to find an exact form that's simpler than the summation.

Comment: Also FWIW, Sagemath returns $2025.9724361499493...$, which is not quite the same as W|A's answer out in the 12th decimal place. Not sure if this helps at all. (Note: Sagemath loves integers and isn't so fond of reals; W|A may be more precise here.)

Comment: @Indecisive can you reveal the source?

Comment: @user376343 Ran across it as a question someone asked on a Discord server, don't know much more than that

Comment: I'm looking again at your route using the complex numbers and wondering why that doesn't work. It sure *looks* like it ought to.

Comment: @EricSnyder Putting it into a calculator, the sum I am trying to find is about 64315, but the sum in my complex numbers approach is about 1479. I believe the issue arises from the imaginary part of the complex number contributing to the value of the denominator (if you were to multiply the numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The computations could be continued with a closed form of Chebyshev polynomials.

An (essentially equivalent) "algebraic" alternative is as follows.
$$\bbox[5pt,border:2pt solid black]{\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{2024}\frac{2023-2022\cos\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2024}}{2021-2020\cos\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2024}}&=2024\left(1+\frac1{1010}\right)-\frac1{2\cdot 1010^2}f_{2024}\left(\frac{2021}{2020}\right),\\
f_n(z)&:=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{z-\cos[(2k-1)\pi/n]}=g_n\left(z\pm\sqrt{z^2-1}\right),\\
g_n(z)&:=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2z}{z^2-2z\cos[(2k-1)\pi/n]+1}=\frac{2nz}{z^2-1}\frac{z^n-1}{z^n+1},
\end{aligned}}$$
and **the last equality** is obtained from the factorization
$$\color{gray}{\left[\prod_{k=1}^n(z-e^{\pm 2k\pi i/n})=z^n-1\implies\right]}\prod_{k=1}^n(z-e^{\pm(2k-1)\pi i/n})=z^n+1.$$

After $(z-e^{it})(z-e^{-it})=z^2-2z\cos t+1$, the product is
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(z^2-2z\cos[(2k-1)\pi/n]+1\right)=(z^n+1)^2.$$
Taking the logarithmic derivative (w.r.t. $z$), we obtain
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{z-\cos[(2k-1)\pi/n]}{z^2-2z\cos[(2k-1)\pi/n]+1}=\frac{nz^{n-1}}{z^n+1}.$$

To get the claimed equality, multiply by $2z$, subtract $n$, and multiply by $\frac{2z}{z^2-1}$.